# 文中の動詞で過去形にする方法について

Tags: python, python3, 自然言語処理

## 実現したいこと

文中の動詞を全て過去形にしたいです。
具体的には以下の入力をして、出力を得るイメージです。

```
As she leaves the kitchen, his voice follows her.

#出力
As she left the kitchen, his voice followed her.
```

## 困っていること

自然言語処理のライブラリを使って、現在形にできることは分かったのですが、過去形にするライブラリや方法がわからず困っています。

## 試したこと

以下の方法で、過去形の動詞を現在形（主語による変形は考慮しない）にできることは、試しました。
[自然言語処理ライブラリspacy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features)のサイトを参考に以下のプログラムを作成しました。

```py
text = "As she left the kitchen, his voice followed her."
doc_dep = nlp(text)
for i in range(len(doc_dep)):
    token = doc_dep[i]
    #print(token.text, token.lemma_, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_) 
    if token.pos_== 'VERB':
        print(token.text)
        print(token.lemma_)
        text = text.replace(token.text, token.lemma_)
print(text)

#出力
'As she leave the kitchen, his voice follow her.'
```

## 環境

Python 3.7.0
spaCy version    2.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pattern.en](https://github.com/clips/pattern)の`conjugate`を使えば任意の時制や人称に変換できます。

#### `pattern`の[インストール](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59419254/8248751)

```
git clone -b development https://github.com/clips/pattern
cd pattern
python setup.py install
```

※Windowsの場合は管理者権限のコンソールで実行してください。

#### サンプルコード

```
from pattern.en import tag, conjugate, PAST, PRESENT, SINGULAR

raw = "OK, I see that she saw sea and I'm not sea."
tags = tag(raw)
print(tags) #[('OK', 'UH'), (',', ','), ('I', 'PRP'), ('see', 'VBP'), ('that', 'IN'), ('she', 'PRP'), ('saw', 'VBD'), ('sea', 'NN'), ('and', 'CC'), ('I', 'PRP'), ("'m", 'VBP'), ('not', 'RB'), ('sea', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]
text = ""
for t in tags:
    s = t[0]
    if t[1] == "VBP":
        s = conjugate(s, tense=PAST)
    #三単現に置換する場合
    #if "VB" in t[1]:
    #    s = conjugate(s, tense=PRESENT, person=3, number=SINGULAR)
    if not(s in ',.'):
        s = ' ' + s
    text += s

print(text.strip()) # OK, I saw that she saw sea and I was not sea.
#三単現に置換した場合 OK, I sees that she sees sea and I is not sea.
```

#### サンプルコード(spaCyと併用する場合)

```
import spacy
from pattern.en import conjugate, PAST

nlp = spacy.load('en')
text = "OK, I see that she saw sea and I'm not sea."
doc_dep = nlp(text)
for i in range(len(doc_dep)):
    token = doc_dep[i]
    if token.pos_== 'VERB':
        text = text.replace(token.text, conjugate(token.text, tense=PAST))

print(text) # OK, I saw that she saw sea and I'm not sea. (※"I'm"が置換されていない)
```

#### 補足

`conjugate`の引数は[本家SOの類似回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42878967/8248751)が詳しいです。
なおPyPIに入っている`pattern`や`pattern3`はメンテナンスが[滞っているよう](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49139945/8248751)で、手元のPython 3.7.2 で`pip install`してもエラーになりました。